# executePendingTransactions conflicts

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some global Loading `fragment` - semi transparent view with loading indicator, I am using it to show loading process instead of creating loading indicator within every fragment, i am attaching it with `add` transaction(also i am using the same instance, i am not creating every time new fragment).

The issue is that some "loading" processes are very fast, and seems like the `remove()` called before the `TransactionManager`executes the transaction, in other words i am trying to remove a fragment that have not been added yet(`loadingFragment.isAdded()==false`), to solve this issue i am tried to use `executePendingTransactions()` after `add()` method, it is solve this problem but lead to another issue:

> FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Where is the balance? how to avoid this kind of conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two solutions:

1. Use `FragmentTransaction.commitNow()` to commit the add fragment synchronously with this call.
2. This is kind of workaround. Wait till add is completed. You can post your remove call on the main thread. If it doesn't work, add some delay.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction.commitNow()` works bellow api 24?

Comment: If you are using support lib, should work for older version as well. `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commitNow()`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i didn't able to solve this using fragments.

`commitNow()` requires no backstack, and most of my fragments need backstack, so `commitNow()` only for `LoadingFragment` may also clash with `FragmentManager is already executing transactions`, and post delayed does not have sense to me.

Instead i was using custom layout(inside single activity application).